# Cannot read property 'token_data' of undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native, realm

I`m trying to get Realm working with a very basic React Native setup, mostly copying code from docs. Strangely, I have problem syncing with realms with a new regular user. On admin everything works fine.

I have authenticated the user with a password. Why would there be a token needed? Or is the problem about permissions? Seems like these states are not anticipated/handled.

This is an error from opening the default realm:

[image: Cannot read property token_data of undefined]

This is from opening other realms:

[image: Unhandled session token]

Here's my code (the issue is both with new Realm and Realm.open, basically every syncing):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { FlatList } from 'react-native'
import Realm from 'realm'

export default class RealmTest extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { realm: null };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        const authURL  = 'https://duel.de1a.cloud.realm.io'
        const realmURL = 'realms://duel.de1a.cloud.realm.io'
        const username = 'test'
        const password = 'test'

        Realm.Sync.User.login(authURL, username, password)
        .then((user) => {
            //Realm.open({
            let realm = new Realm({
                schema: [ { name: 'Dog', properties: { name: 'string' } } ],
                sync: { user, url: realmURL},
                //schemaVersion: 1
            })
            //.then((realm) => {
            const dogs = realm.objects('Dog');
            dogs.addListener(() => {
                this.forceUpdate();
            });
            this.setState({ realm });
            //});
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.warn("Authentication failed")
        });
    }

    renderList(realm) {
        if (! realm) {
            return <Text>"No realm objects"</Text>
        }
        else {
            return (
                <FlatList
                    data={realm.objects('Dog')}
                    keyExtractor={(item) => item.name}
                    renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.name}</Text>}
                />
            )
        }
    }

    render() {
        const info = this.state.realm
        ? 'Number of dogs in this Realm: ' + this.state.realm.objects('Dog').length
        : 'Loading...';

        return (
            <View>
                {this.renderList(this.state.realm)}
                <Text>{info}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: im having same problem did you ever get a resolution for this ?

Comment: Not really, I ditched Realm for Firebase and never looked back